# Making a slow running macro run more quickly and efficiently

Tags: vba, ms-word

I have created a macro that inserts a standard corporate classification that indicates that the information in the document is unclassified but is "for official use only." This is expressed as (U//FOUO) which appears before every body paragraph. I have also created a macro that inserts the same text expression before each level of numbered headings used the book. My book is a large (~665 pages) Microsoft Word file. It is also very "dense" with many paragraphs, tables, and illustrations. Although my macros work successfully, they are very slow and take from about 6 to 10 minutes to complete. When the macros complete, a Runtime Error '28' (out of stack space) is displayed. I don't know if the length of time is a result of inefficient coding on my part or a reflection of the density/complexity/length of the book.

Could you suggest changes to the code below to make it run more efficiently? Or maybe just indicate whether the "delays" might simply be a natural and expected result of the length of the document? My code is as follows:

```
Public Sub InsertFOUObody()

    'Inserts U//FOUO before all body paragraphs
    Dim doc As Document
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim paraNext As Paragraph
    Dim MyText As String
    Set doc = ActiveDocument
    Set para = doc.Paragraphs.First

    Do While Not para Is Nothing
        Set paraNext = para.Next
        MyText = "(U//FOUO) "
        If para.Style = doc.Styles(wdStyleBodyText) Then
            para.Range.InsertBefore (MyText)
        End If
        Set para = paraNext
    Loop

End Sub
```

When I try to debug the code, I get the impression that the offending line is `Set paraNext = para.next`. However, as a newbie to VBA I can't recognize why this line of code is at fault. The code seems to be generating far more calls than necessary.

Comment: From the looks of it, you probably need to disable Screen Updating while this subroutine is running.

Answer (score 0):

The following code should be faster, because:

1. `Do While` was changed with `For`, this way you count the number of paragraphs once and you never return to the calculation. When you had `Do While Not para Is Nothing`, in every iteration you had to make sure if `Not para Is Nothing`.
2. Less `Set`; no `Set` in the main part which is iterating. These statements add some time burden.
3. You do not `MyText = "(U//FOUO) "` in every iteration. Instead, you state it once and forever at the beginning by making it a constant (constants are generally faster than usual strings).

```
Public Sub InsertFOUObody2()
```

`'Inserts U//FOUO before all body paragraphs
    Const MyText As String = "(U//FOUO) "
    Dim i As Long
    Dim doc As Document
    Set doc = ActiveDocument

    For i = 1 To doc.Paragraphs.Count
        With doc.Paragraphs(i)
            If .Style = doc.Styles(wdStyleBodyText) Then
                .Range.InsertBefore (MyText)
            End If
        End With
    Next

End Sub`

Comment: Thank you so much ZygD. I greatly appreciate the time you spent in responding. It's near the end of my workday but I will try your macro tomorrow morning. I also appreciate your "educational" analysis in 1, 2, 3 above. I am trying to get to the point where I can recognize better approaches to take and your comments help me in that long-term effort. I'll let you know how the changed macro performs. Thank you